# Problema timers js

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, timer

Tenho uma aplicação web e esta tem PaginaPrincipal, PaginaEntidade e PaginaNoticia e a cada uma destas está associado um ficheiro JS. O objectivo é começar na paginaPrincipal e passado x tempo ir para a paginaEntidade e passado x tempo ir para a paginaNoticia. Eu usei o setInterval do JS e funciona mas com um problema, como faz load das paginas está sempre a carregar o script de novo e então está sempre a executar o timer... Alguma solução para resolver isto ?

Comment: As três páginas são independentes? ou seja tem mesmo de recarregar a página? Pode mudar o url para ter um token/query string que o script procura e bloqueia. Tipo flag a dizer que já correu.

Comment: Mais um pormenor, depois também preciso de fazer o caminho inverso, ou seja paginaNoticia, paginaEntidade, paginaPrincipal. Por isso não sei se funciona essa solução. O que a aplicação faz é simular um clique num botão da paginaPrincipal e é construída a próxima pagina (paginaEntidade) com os dados correspondentes ao botão que foi clicado

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você pode fazer diferente. Crie uma página e carregue o conteúdo através de requisições ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Você pode carregar conteúdos dentro de uma div, por exemplo. O timer pode fazer requisições para estas mudanças.